# Get the sum of listview Item and int value

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am making a shopping cart. I have 3 textbox(txtItemCode,txtItemName,txtQuantity) so everytime I add an item it will display to my '`listView1`' that has 3 columns(ItemCode,ItemName,Quantity) on button click and I also have a 'panel1' that will show the Total Amount of the items in the cart the '`panel1`' has 2 labels(TaxLabel,AmountLabel).

Every single number in Quantity of an item is equivalent to 120

I want to see in '`panel1`' the total price based on the quantity items in my cart

in my code I can get the total price of the items in my cart but I'm also getting the input of the textbox '`txtQuantity.Text`' and I can't get rid of it 
heres my code:

```
int x = int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text);
foreach (ListViewItem li in listView1.Items)
{
    x += int.Parse(li.SubItems[2].Text) * 120;
}
labelItemAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(x);
```

Comment: It seems you are overriding the value of x in each iteration, why is that?

Comment: sorry wrong copy.Edited post now

Comment: Can you show an example of what is the content of the subItem at index 2? I don't understand your question in the part where you talk abount of the txtQuantity textbox

Comment: What is in txtQuantity? What is it in relation with the table of items?

Comment: put breakpoint. use debugger. goodluck

Comment: @MaorVeitsman its a textbox sorry wrong copy

Comment: Why don't you initialize x with 0 at the start?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman same result sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think its better to use the value of quantity subitem instead of 120, you can use such code to get sum:

```
var sum = this.listView1.Items
              .Cast<ListViewItem>()
              .Sum(item => int.Parse(item.SubItems[2].Text)* 120);
labelItemAmount.Text = sum.ToString();
```

If you want to use value of quantity subitem, supposing index of quantity subitem is 3, use `int.Parse(item.SubItems[3].Text)` instead of 120.

Also don't forget to add `using SystemLinq;`

Comment: @Steve Yes, thank you, I just typed something with minimum risk, I'll change it.